# Query today's input

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to query/select only today's input by the user in SQL/PHP.

For example. If the user puts "blue" as an input today, I want the query to display "blue", but if the user tomorrow inputs "green", the query should display "green" tomorrow.

Comment: Then store that color. You don't even need a database for this. You can use a textfile to store the color and it is valid until it gets changed (daily in your case).

Comment: I'm going to use it on a bigger scale. And it's data submitted through form and stored in a database.
The user will enter numbers daily. After that, we will have to do some math and then display a result that will have to change on a daily basis according to the daily inputs.

Comment: It's better to provide a sample of input and the expected output data, based on the description you provided it's something like `select user_color from User_Inputs where input_date = NOW()`

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Date functions differ a lot from one database system to another. Then, what are you actually asking? Your request doesn't contain any question. Do you have a database with a table containing the information? If so, describe that table. Will there be exactly one entry per day? What to do if there is no entry for today (yet)? What have *you* done so far? What keeps you from writing the query? It sounds simple, so what is the issue you are facing?